# Межпроцессное взаимодействие

Tags: c

Представим, что между двумя парами процессов инициализированы pipe и fifo соответственно. Какое может возникнуть отличие в их работе, если они взаимодействуют одинаково?

Answer (score 2):

Главное отличие, которое мне сразу приходит, это то, что трубы можно сделать только между родственными процессами. Далее, если пайп закрыт, то он теряется, а фифо можно всегда открыть заново, да и с новыми параметрами.

Comment: @mikillskegg, а что такое родственные процессы? Несколько процессов, запускаемых одной шелл-командой -- они родственные значит. Тогда да, к именованным трубам обращаются по имени и родственные связи необязательны.

Comment: @Дмитрий Инкирев, если ответ помог, отмечаем его плюсиком.

@alexiz, я ничего не понял. Какие проблемы?

Comment: Что значит "родственные процессы"?

Comment: Здесь я имел в виду процессы "родительский-дочерний" или "братские".

Comment: А если "тётя-племянница"?

Comment: Сегодня стёб отменяется

Comment: Так зачем его начинать? Можно просто объяснить, что значит "родственные процессы". А фраза "родительский-дочерний или братский" -- это и есть стёб. Нарисовать текст для процессов "тётя-племянница", связанных неименованной трубой вроде не сложно.

Comment: Неименованные каналы можно организовать только между процессами, происходящими от одного предка, который эти каналы и организовал, или между этим родительским процессом и каким-то происходящим от него. Так понятнее?

Comment: Ну спасибо, уважили. Это уже понятно. А род-потомок, братья и прочие вполне возможны, хотя более причудливые схемы и менее вероятны. Правда в linux'ах вроде есть чёрный ход для имеющих привилегии -- /proc/PID/fd/

Comment: а вот разберитесь с этим подходом и расскажите нам.

Comment: Это вы об чём?. Как через /proc подцепиться к трубе? man proc. Хохма в том, что труба должна существовать, т.е. оба процесса быть живы. Иллюстрация: в одном окне сделать `cat | cat`, в другом `ps ax | grep cat`, затем в другом окне `sudo cat /proc/PID2/fd/0` или `sudo  cat >/proc/PID1/fd/1` и понажимать на клавиши. Или вы о чём-то другом?

Comment: Хохма в том, что достаточно, чтобы был жив хотя бы один процесс и хотя бы один конец трубы был открыт. И можно даже без прав суперпользователя. (У меня получилось. )

Comment: Ну это же Ваши процессы, они хозяина должны знать. А насчёт одного конца -- не понял, как можно подцепиться к сломанной трубе (когда второй процесс уже получил broken pipe). Или сначала подцепиться, а потом сломать?

Comment: Сначала написал, потом понял, что написал глупость. 

А сделать трубу между процессами-потомками одного процесса весьма просто.

Comment: Да, /proc/PID/fd/xxx в Linux это очень интересно. 

--

Интересно, если процесс имеет открытый сокет (неважно по сети или локальный), "опубликовал" его fd, а сам висит на чем-нибудь другом (например sleep()), то вновь запущенный (неродственный, но с нужными привиллегиями) процесс (зная этот fd) сможет общаться под видом спящего ?

--

По крайней мере в примере с cat > ./xaxa и cat >/proc/2248/fd/1 оба пишут в ./xaxa (только трут друг друга, т.к. позицию в файле не разделяют).

Comment: Попытка `cat`ом работать с сокетом (не серверным listen, обычным, после accept) не получилась. Говорит "Нет такого устройства или адреса". Там же симлинки. для файлов они на /dev, а вот для сокета -- на socket:[155011]. И не понимает cat.